# How to choose image from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-gallery

First of all ,i'm new on programming Android.
I want to choose an image from gallery and upload it.
All of this from a Fragment.
The problem is that when I choose the image from a fragment ,return to the First Fragment ,not the fragment that called it.
I searched about this, but after choose image not return to *onActivityResult*
This https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-fix-nested-fragment-onactivityresult-issue/en doesn't work for me
Thanks

This is my code

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("fragment","fragment");
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            // Get the url from data
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                // Get the path from the Uri
                String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                //Log.i(TAG, "Image Path : " + path);
                // Set the image in ImageView

            }
        }
    }
}

    void openImageChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);

}
```

**UPDATE: RESOLVED**

I do all said the post except the calling for startActivityForResult

```
    void openImageChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
}

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 122) {
        // Do your job

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                // Get the url from data
                selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                    // Get the path from the Uri
                    String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                    //Log.i(TAG, "Image Path : " + path);
                    // Set the image in ImageView
                    guardar();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just use `startActivityForResult` without getActivity first. Otherwise, implement onActivityResult in the parent Activity of the Fragment

Comment: tried,but nothing.
When i choose the image returns to the first Fragment

Comment: That post goes over everything you need. Try reading again?

Comment: I read all the post again and remake the code again and nothing.
Do you know any way more easy to do this?

Comment: Can you [edit] your post with your updated code? How much debugging did you do to determine it didn't work?

Comment: Updated the code. But the problem now is that when I chose the image , returns to the main activity not to the fragment, but the code escutes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Reading that post...

> all of the result received will be handled at the single place:  onActivityResult of the Activity that Fragment is placed on.

So, move your onActivityResult to the Activity.

Makes sense because the Activity started the intent, not the Fragment itself.

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult
```

Comment: Yes, I have this in my Activity
`@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ActivityResultBus.getInstance().postQueue(
                new ActivityResultEvent(requestCode, resultCode, data));
    }` but nothing ,doesn't work

Comment: I don't know what this bus thing is doing, but if you're using Otto like that post says, you need to subscribe to the event from the Fragment, I believe

Comment: Yes , I have the methods onStart,onStop and mActivityResultSubscriber in Fragment.
 I read all the post again and remake the code again and nothing. Do you know any way more easy to do this?

Comment: My problem is resolved,         startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
withhout getActivity, the rest the same